# How to update current String(Not int) value of the listView to the spinner while clicking on listView?

Tags: java, android

How to update current String(Not int) value of the listView to the spinner to the next activity.
This TRANS String value i want to update in next screen when i click on listView.
[image]

Comment: I don't get your question. Do you want to know how you can show a String in a spinner?

Comment: Yes.. The above TRANS String of listView i want to display in next screen's spinner.